# Algorithm to create multiple lists from a single list

Tags: java, list

I have an interface:

```
List<List<Integer>> separate(List<Integer> list);
```

I want to be able to separate the parameterized list into separate integer lists based on if the values within the list object are the same so if the list was `{1, 1, 5, 7, 9}` it would create 4 separate lists:

- `{1, 1}`
- `{5}`
- `{7}`
- `{9}`

Is there an easy library to use for this? I can quite easily come up with an algorithm which does this but if the elements in the list were not `Integers` but `Objects` and you wanted to base the grouping rules on some fields within it then how would I go about doing that?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'd want to use a temporary `Map<Key, List<Type>>`, where *Key* and *Type* would both be `Integer` in your example. For each `Integer` in the big list, check the `Map` to see if that `Integer` is already a key. If not, then add it with a new `List<Integer>`. Then either way, add the `Integer` to the `List` for that key. Then at the very end, construct `List<Integer>` from the `values()` of the `Map`.

For a more complicated *Type*, you'd choose some distinguishing data value to be the *Key*, but otherwise the code would be analogous.

Comment: Ah thanks, very useful approach think I'll apply this approach in combination with decorator pattern to apply multiple rules onto certain fields in the case where Integer is an object with certain fields.